# follow up blogs for Flink Serialization Tuning Vol. 1

Tags: apache-flink

I am reading at https://flink.apache.org/news/2020/04/15/flink-serialization-tuning-vol-1.html. It is very helpful material about flink type system. At the end,it ways:

> The next article in this series will use this finding as a starting point to look into a few common pitfalls and obstacles of avoiding Kryo, how to get the most out of the PojoSerializer, and a few more tuning techniques with respect to serialization. Stay tuned for more.

But I didn't find the next articles...looks the author didn't publish the next article?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(So far) there is no part 2, but you might enjoy [A Journey to Beating Flink's SQL Performance](https://www.ververica.com/blog/a-journey-to-beating-flinks-sql-performance) from the same author.